# Linestrings into one multilinestring

Tags: postgis, linestring

I have 2 tables `"dijkstra_results_geo"` and `"dijkstra_results_geo_aggregate"`.
I have a set of Linestrings in the column dijkstra_results_geo.geom_path_intermediaire (defined as geometry(Linestring, 4326)).

I would like to collect all these Linestrings into one big Multilinestring in the column dijkstra_results_geo_aggregate.path (1 row with gid=1).
I tried :

```
 UPDATE dijkstra_results_geo_aggregate  
 SET path = (SELECT St_Union(dijkstra_results_geo.geom_path_intermediaire)  
FROM dijkstra_results_geo)
 WHERE gid=1;
```

The query works but the "path" column (defined as geometry(Multilinestring, 4326)) remains empty.

I also tried to use `St_Collect` but it's empty as well.

I finally tried the query with the "path" and "geom_path_intermediaire" columns defined as "geometry", but it's the same.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you tried ST_Multi ? http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Multi.html

Comment: Yes, I get :  "0105000020E610000057000000010200000002000000000000001E8F2741000000801B6B5A410000000018982741000000C09C6A5A410102000000020000000000000066A82741000000C0FF6C5A410000000094C2274100000080AA6E5A410102000000020000000000000018982741000000C09C6A5A410000000012A52741 (...)"

Comment: If I try st_Multi, I get : "ERREUR:  plus d'une ligne renvoyée par une sous-requête utilisée comme une expression"
(it means there are several rows as result so it can't fit into one row.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I succeded with  :

```
UPDATE dijkstra_results_geo_aggregate  
SET path = (SELECT st_LineMerge(St_Union(dijkstra_results_geo.geom_path_intermediaire))   
FROM dijkstra_results_geo)
WHERE gid=1;
```

Thanks you so much for your help!  ;)